# Evaluate the sum $\lim_{t\to{1-0}}(1-t)(\frac{t}{1+t}+\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}+...+\frac{t^n}{1+t^n}+...)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a question about this limit.
Calculate$$\lim_{t\to{1-0}}(1-t)(\frac{t}{1+t}+\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}+...+\frac{t^n}{1+t^n}+...)$$
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h=-\log t$. Then

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{t\nearrow 1}(1-t)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t^k}{1+t^k}
&=&
\lim_{t\nearrow 1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1-t)\frac1{1+t^{-k}}
\\
&=&
\lim_{h\searrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1-\mathrm e^{-h})\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{kh}}
\\
&=&
\lim_{h\searrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(h+O(h^2))\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{kh}}
\\
&=&
\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+\mathrm e^x}\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\log2\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Cool!How can you think of this?

Comment: @Gingerjin: I'll try to retrace my thinking. I noticed that $t^k/(1+t^k)=1/(1+t^{-k})$, so each term is just $1/(1+x)$ evaluated at different points $x_k=t^{-k}$, and those points move closer and closer together as $t\to1$, while the whole thing gets multiplied by something that goes to $0$. That suggested to view this as a sum that becomes an integral in the limit, but it wasn't quite right because the points weren't equidistant, so I worked out the transformation that made them equidistant.

Comment: @joriki I'm used to transforming infinite sums to integrals over finite intervals. How do you note the upper limit is necessarily $\infty$? How would you construct the $\Delta x_i$'s in such a case?

Comment: @Peter: The interval length here is $h$. I'm not sure I understand the question about $\infty$. The summation index $k$ runs up to $\infty$, so I don't see how the upper limit of the integral could be anything other than $\infty$.

Comment: @joriki Missed that. The thing is I usually use, let's say

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{n + k}}}  = \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{1 + x}} = \log 2} $$ and the upper limit depends on the partitions, $n$, not on the interval.

Comment: @Peter: I see, interesting. I guess those are different situations in that the summation limit occurs in the summand in one case but not the other.